# Patch Panel/Wiring Question

Tags: patch-panel

The reason I am asking this is that I am an amateur, so if it is obvious to you, it's not to me, so please explain.

I saw this picture and I panicked a little bit,

1. First of all I know older patch panels had two sides one side that you punch the Ethernet in and the other side is where the actual feeder/port of the Ethernet is, these new models have ports on both sides, so you don't have to punch things in, is that true?
2. where are the switches/routers in this picture? do they install all the patch panels on one rack and switch/routers will be on the next rack?
3. can you help me figure out where all those patch cables are going, that I marked up?, which one goes to the switches, which one goes to the building rooms? (ofc this is not your design, me neither, just make a guess, it helps me understand the typical pattern of these[image]

thx

Comment: (1) bulkhead keystones have been around for (internet)centuries. (2) impossible to say as they aren't pictured. (3) nope. "not my network" so I cannot say where any of those go, or what they are. (stack exchange is not a place for guessing.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Sorry, questions about networks (and installations) that you don't control are explicitly off-topic here. We can't just guess.

Answer (score 3):

> First of all I know older patch panels had two sides one side that you punch the Ethernet in and the other side is where the actual feeder/port of the Ethernet is, these new models have port on both sides, so you don't have to punch things in, is that true?

Most patch panels require the infrastructure runs to be punched down. Most vendors still require punch downs on their patch panels for a certified installation.

While I have seen patch panels as you describe, they have always been intended for non-permanent installations or must use the vendor's entire solution to reliably pass the cabling certification.

> where are the switches/routers in this picture? do they installed all the patch panels on one rack and switch/routers will be on the next rack?

This looks like a picture by some vendor illustrating different cable management solutions. As such, switches or routers are not useful for the product being highlighted and contrasted.

> can you help me figure where all those patch cables are going, that I marked up?, which one goes to the switches, which one goes to the building rooms?(ofc this is not your design, me neither, just make a guess, it helps me understand the typical pattern of these

Given my answer to your previous question, they may go nowhere for all we know as they don't need to go anywhere for the purpose of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

That picture is from a sales video made by [FS](https://www.fs.com/) advertising their [horizontal cable managers for Ethernet cabling](https://www.fs.com/products/29039.html?attribute=6426&id=259701) (see timestamp 1:24 of the video). The wiring in that rack isn't necessarily supposed to represent a typical real-word scenario. Instead, that picture is supposed to make you panic a bit—as you stated—and then convince you to buy some cable managers made by FS. That's why there aren't any switches, routers, or servers shown in the picture. The only items depicted are cable managers and patch panels with the FS logo.

Cable managers and patch panels are useful and should be used where they make sense, but your rack will most likely include other equipment and not look identical to this picture.